# ErrorException in mycontroller on line 137 Undefined offset: 2

Tags: laravel-5

I am getting this exception: Undefined offset: 2 when inserting a multidimensional array in the database. This is my loop at which the error is pointing at:

```
$order_details = [];
for($i= 0; $i < count($product); $i++){
    $order_details[] = [
        'order_id' => $orders->id,
        'product_id' => $product['product_id'][$i],
        'units'=>4,
        'quantity' => $product['quantity'][$i],
        'unit_price' => $product['price'][$i],
        'product_discount_id'=>0,
        'amount' => $product['amount'][$i],
    ];
}
```

When I echo my array seems to look fine:

```
Array ( [product_id] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 1 ) [quantity] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1 ) [price] => Array ( [0] => 200.00 [1] => 700.00 ) [amount] => Array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 700 ) )
```

The undefined offset value alternates depending on how many items from the shopping cart are passed to the loop. For example if there are 3 items the error is set to Undefined offset:3
Its like I cannot find out the real mole. I have searched the web I have not managed any way out.
Any assistance Kindly. what May I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The errors you are getting are about not having an element with index of `count($product)`.

You should just use:

`for($i= 0; $i <`**`count($product)-1`**`; $i++)`

This way you loop will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's kind of an odd array structure. You'd have a much easier time working with the data if you rearranged it like this so you have an item per product:

```
$products = [
    [
        'product_id' => 7,
        'quantity' => 2,
        'price' => 200.00,
        'amount' => 400 
    ],
    [
        'product_id' => 1,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'price' => 700.00,
        'amount' => 700
    ]
];
```

Then you can just foreach over the products.

The fix for your problem though is this `for($i= 0; $i <= count($product); $i++)`

Comment: Thanks Jim. for($i= 0; $i <= count($product); $i++) retains the same error.

Comment: I have also tried your suggested array structure which displays correctly on print_r() but returns ErrorException in helpers.php line 686:
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array when I run the code

Comment: Just see what I have done. I am doing something wrong I guese

Comment: for($i= 0; $i <= count($product); $i++) { $products = [ [ 'order_id' => $orders->id, 'product_id' => $product['product_id'], 'units'=>4, 'quantity' => $product['quantity'], 'price' => $product['price'], 'product_discount_id'=>0, 'amount' => $product['amount'] ], ]; }

Comment: What does the array `$product` contain?